# Arduino nano as Part of another circuit

Tags: arduino

Im a very beginner with electronics and started with Arduino. So I tried to make a little device which is a separate board which is being work based on digital out and few output port from Arduino. But rather than separate board system , I would like to make Arduino and my custom board together. Is that possible or from where I could get the good circuit for Arduino nano with its all mandatory components including the bootloader.

Important point is the device Im trying to build is something which is intended to run 365x24x7 (No worries about power failure, its running on perfect backup system)

Also another concern is I dont need all the IO pins I just need 3-4 pins from Arduino. So is that requires any serious changes on the Arduino circuitry. Sorry because of my poor knowledge in electronics Im sharing that stupid question.

Please share your kind thoughts.

Comment: Which Arduino?  There are a wide range of Arduino boards available, the schematics are all available by googling the name of the board + schematic and the bootloaders are provided with the Arduino software development kit.

Comment: Sorry,I mentioned Arduino Nano there in the description

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full schematic for most arduino boards by googling "arduino **board name** schematic". For the most part, a bare bones arduino is just a Atmel microcontroller, a capacitor or two, a few resistors and a voltage source. Then you add things like an external crystal for a better clock, a serial to usb adapter, a voltage regulator, etc as needed. Now you can get a microcontroller that has the usb to serial part built in really. And plenty of places sell just the pre-programmed microcontroller for you.

As the cost of the microcontroller is like a few dollars at best, you might as well stick with a ATmega with more pins, instead of going with the smaller, cheaper, but weaker ATtiny cousins.

Comment: "And plenty of places sell just the pre-programmed microcontroller for you." Because of my very low knowledge in electronics, I didn't understand this point.. can you please share little more information

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this will be much help, but a method I'm currently entertaining is soldering two sets of female headers that the arduino nano will plug right into,  Then on the PCB the female headers are attached to I have my custom circuitry allowing me to interface with the nano, with also the option to "hotswap" the nano out.

The spacing between the two rows of headers are .6" with 2.54mm spacing between pins.  (Two rows of 15)

Not the cleanest way of doing it, but it fits my requirements.